# PHP doesn't echo posted value from jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Clicking on div `#some_id` calls `details.php` but it doesn't succeed in retrieving data from jQuery. `details.php` is supposed to echo `123`.

My goal is that when I click on div `#some_id`, `details.php` shows `123` in the browser.

html:

```
<div id="some_id">
<a href="details.php"> Details </a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function detailsClick(){
    $("#some_id").live('click', function(){
        var data = {'myData': 123};
        $.post('details.php', data);
    });
}
```

details.php:

```
<?php
$idNumber =  $_POST["myData"];
echo ($idNumber);
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you're confused about ajax. You have a link which will reload the page and a Javascript ajax request to the same file that won't reload the page. You aren't using the result from the ajax request, so I assume you're just reloading the page, which has nothing to do with the js code. Perhaps you want to get rid of the Javascript code and just make your link details.php?myData=123 and use $_GET ['myData']

Comment: @m59 Thanks very much for your help. Sorry, I am very new to all of this. Can you please tell me what I need to do? I couldnt quite follow you...

Comment: @m59 if I remove my JS code how am I supposed to retrieve that data?

Comment: FYI `live()` is deprecated and has been removed from the latest versions of jQuery. You should use `on()` instead.

Comment: My jQuery is rusty - does `$.post` automatically send `data` as `application/json`? If so, the data won't actually be able to read the data from `$_POST` - instead you have to read it with `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');` and then `$data = json_decode($json, true)`.

Comment: You should be able to check the content type of the request with `echo $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];`, if that helps.

Comment: Okay, I just read your question properly ;) - to echo @m59, it does look like you're confused about ajax because you are not handling the return value from PHP. To do this, either follow his advice, or chain a `.success()` handler to your `$.post` call; e.g: `$.post('details.php', data).success(function(data) { alert(data); });`.

Comment: @Darragh thanks a lot. Sorry but I am pretty new to all of this. Do I then need to change my html?

Comment: @lioli YOu need tot use `$.ajax()`. `$.post()` wont help you.

Answer (score 7):

> I believe that you are not getting click event here. Change jQuery code as below.

```
$(function(){
    $("#some_id").on('click', function(){
        var data = {'myData': '123'};
        $.post( "details.php", data)
            .done(function( data ) {
                 alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @lioli can you please change `echo ($idNumber);` to simple `echo $idNumber;`

Comment: @lioli Did you load jQuery before the function?

Answer (score 2):

1. `.live()` is deprecated. Use `.on()` instead.
2. The function `detailsClick()` is never called. So the `onclick` listener is **NOT** registered.

Either do this.

```
function detailsClick(){
    $("#some_id").live('click', function(){
        var data = {'myData': 123};
        $.post('details.php', data);
    });
}

detailsClick();
```

OR do this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#some_id").live('click', function(){
        var data = {'myData': 123};
        $.post('details.php', data);
    });
});
```

ALSO, you need to use AJAX for what you want to do.

Refer [AJAX with jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't display anything because the link is being followed, with no post data.

```
<a href="details.php"> Details </a>
```

Ajax is used to get data without changing pages. It seems as if you want to navigate to the details page.

If you want the page to navigate to `details.php`, use a normal html form with submit button.

If you want to return data WITHOUT changing pages

Details

```
$("#some_id").on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault().
      var data = {'myData': 123};
      $.post('details.php', data)
          .done(function(response){
              // data is available here
              console.log(response);
          });
 });
```